# Bootstrap 3 Modal auto size, 30 pix from sides

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to build modal window that will be positioned absolute, 30 pixels from edge of screen.

[image]

I've build this css:

```
.modal {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.modal-dialog {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    margin: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .modal-dialog {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
.modal-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.modal-header, .modal-body, .modal-footer {
    padding: 10px;
}
.modal-content {
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.modal-backdrop {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.modal-header .close {
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.btn {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

and my results so far looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/LT3YM/

My modal window is correctly positioned, but modal-body isn't sizing, i would like it to take rest of available height of modal - from header to footer.
I can position absolute modal-body and add top and bottom properties, but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

My solution for now is this code:

```
.modal-body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 46px;
    bottom: 54px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and demo of what I have:
[image]

**How can I modify my code better so that modal-body will always be correct height?** Is positioning it absolutely only option?

Comment: 30px left from edge of the screen? It sounds like you want to kill the bottom property and just put top: 30px; left: 30px;

Comment: @rnirnber - I would like my modal to be positioned 30 px from every edge, because text that will be showed there will be long, so I want user to be able to scroll content of my modal and not entire page.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LT3YM/1/ checkout is this what you want

Comment: Can we have a more clear description of what and how do you want your modal to look like. Thank you.

Comment: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/07/css-overlay-techniques/ this will might help

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/LT3YM/4/

You should change the values in `.modal-dialog`. You can make `bottom` and `right` `30px` too

```
.modal-dialog {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 50px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[image]

Alternatively, this uses 3%: http://jsfiddle.net/LT3YM/7/

```
.modal-dialog {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%;
    bottom: 3%;
    left: 3%;
    right: 3%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/LT3YM/3/ please look at this site, this is the result I would like to get. Try to resize page and look how modal-body is resizing. I'm just wondering if there is a better way of doing this - I want this to work in ie, chrome and ff

Comment: Yes I've seen it, but problem is that modal-body is fixed size, I would like it to autoheight

Comment: I see, but you said in comments, 30px from every edge?

Comment: I'll prepare fast demo, give me a second

Comment: I have edited my answer with a % value and animation.

Comment: @AliGajani how is that image moving is that a gif

Comment: please see my question, I've added demo

Comment: So, again, what's the problem?

Comment: Do i must use `position: absolute` of `.modal-bod`y and write all that css, maybe bootstrap has this build-in.

Comment: BS doesn't have everything built in, so its fine this way.

Comment: I'll leave this open, maybe I'll figure out something, anyway thanks for such fast response :)